# Add border to UIButtons frame

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, border, frame

A UIButton, created in the Interface Builder, has a frame with the size: 240×40.
When trying to add a single line border around it, the border appears around the text instead of the UIButtons frame.

**ViewController.m**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[LoginButton layer] setCornerRadius:20.0f];
    [[LoginButton layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [[LoginButton layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
}
```

No additional changes to the UIButton were made. Logging its size will result in: 240×40

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: Uh, how to fix this?
I want a border around the buttons frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use auto layout? Make sure that the width constraint matches the frame width you've set.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom `View` that has a `UIButton` as a subview. The containing view will act as the border and you can handle all sizing and etc. in detail as you want.